# Unable to fetch key vault values through azure app config in spring boot app

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-configuration, azure-spring-cloud, azure-spring-boot

**Issue Description**

We need to fetch key vault secret values provided as a key reference in Azure app config. We are able to fetch values present in app config but not the key references to key vault secrets.

**Platform**

Spring Boot
OS: Windows (running app locally)
IDE: Eclipse
Java 1.8

**Setup instructions followed**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-spring-boot
https://github.com/saragluna/demo-appconfiguration-kv

**Dependencies**

```
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>

<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-web</artifactId>
<version>1.2.7</version>
```

**bootstrap.properties in resource folder**

```
Values are provided as vm arguments at startup time.

spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string=${endpoint app config}
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.uri=${key vault url}
azure.keyvault.client-id=${service principal client-id}
azure.keyvault.client-key=${service principal secret key}
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=${service principal tenant-id}
```

**Exceptions trace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Max retries 3 times exceeded. Error Details: connect timed out
at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.lambda$attemptAsync$1(RetryPolicy.java:119) ~[azure-core-1.6.0.jar:na]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:545) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:545) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:196) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2346) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:143) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:182) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:431) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:514) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:536) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:427) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:562) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:425) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1518) ~[netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1279) ~[netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1316) ~[netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.stores.KeyVaultClient.getSecret(KeyVaultClient.java:98) ~[spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.AppConfigurationPropertySource.getKeyVaultEntry(AppConfigurationPropertySource.java:180) ~[spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.AppConfigurationPropertySource.initProperties(AppConfigurationPropertySource.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator.create(AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator.java:222) ~[spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator.addPropertySource(AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator.java:150) ~[spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator.locate(AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator.java:101) ~[spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:98) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at com.kcc.control_tower.Application.main(Application.java:39) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.lambda$checkIMDSAvailable$14(IdentityClient.java:462) ~[azure-identity-1.0.4.jar:na]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:91) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]

... 55 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you set access policy fro the application in key vault?

Comment: According to my test, we can access key vault reference by referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-spring-boot

Comment: @JimXu yes i got it resolved , with the approach provided in document i was using connection string but i had to use endpoint of app config

Answer (score 0):

I summarize the solution as below.

if we want to access the key vault reference in Azure App Configuration,  we need to provide the endpoint in `bootstrap.properties`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-spring-boot)

For example

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].endpoint= ${APP_CONFIGURATION_ENDPOINT}
```